# Publish BizTalk orchestration as wcf service into remote IIS

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-deployment, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to publish my BizTalk Orchestration to IIS. When I try with my local IIS it is working. But when I try with a remote IIS it says host not found.

Is there any way to do this?

I am using BizTalk Server 2013 R2 and IIS 8.5 In the remote server BizTalk server developer version is installed

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the service on a remote computer?  Look into BTDF.  Are you trying to access the service from a remote computer?  Make sure that ports are open in your firewall and that you're configured to accept requests from the remote computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your "local IIS" is a development environment where you develop on BizTalk and publish the orchestration as a service.  After you do that, and you know it all works on your development environment you need to export an msi on your development box using BizTalk Administrator, and import it onto the other BizTalk environment (your "remove IIS"), using BizTalk Administrator.

Comment: As per my knowledge, exporting as msi creates a new application in the biztalk administration. What i want to do is publish my wcf service in another server than my local development IIS.

Comment: Exporting an msi does not create a new application.  Importing one can. But you can avoid that by only exporting the service portion.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *Publish* to a remote IIS server.  You can *Deploy* a Published Service to any IIS instance.

You can do this by exporting an .msi with the Service included or BTDF.

Comment: I want to publish orchestration as wcf service in another server than my local development IIS. not deploying the biztalk application is another server.

Comment: I understand that, and you still can't do it.  You can only Publish locally.  You have to then export and Deploy to the other server.  Keep in mind, BizTalk must be installed there as well.

Comment: Is there any prerequisites that needs to be done for using the deployed client? I am gettiing "the document specification from assembly failed to load" error when using the svc from server but local one works fine

Comment: You must Import and run the .msi on the IIS server, just like installing on an in-process BizTalk Host Computer.  Keep in mind, the IIS server is just another BizTalk Host computer.